# UIButton doesn't "blink" on every tap

Tags: ios, uibutton

I have 3 `UIButtons` in a `UIView` that have the same text colour and the same background colour. On tap all three of them fire their corresponding event. But only one of them "blinks" in response to the touch. What can be happening with the other two? They sometimes (but rarely) have the "blink" behaviour, but the `touch up inside event` is always fired on tap.

The buttons are added in `storyboard`:

[image]

Comment: set background color for highlight state then

Comment: @ktrkathir I just tried your suggestion. I subclassed UIButton and have overriden the `isHighlighted` var . I am having a similar issue like the described. It gets highlighted only sometimes (rarely). The `touch event` fires every time though.

Answer (score 1):

```
 func btnFlash_Clicked(sender: AnyObject) {
     if !flashing{
        callButton.alpha = 1.0
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.0, options: [.allowUserInteraction], animations: {() -> Void in
            callButton.alpha = 0.5
        }, completion: {(finished: Bool) -> Void in
        })

        flashing = true
     } else{
        flashing = false
        callButton.alpha = 0.5
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.0, options: [.allowUserInteraction], animations: {() -> Void in
            callButton.alpha = 1.0
        }, completion: {(finished: Bool) -> Void in
        })
```

Comment: I think your idea of animating the alpha of the button works well, but I don't understand the flashing variable and checks. Can you explain some more?

Answer (score 1):

I would setup the button type to UIButtonTypeCustom to stop blinking.